# WindowManager.addView() - "Unable to add window - token null is not valid; is your activity running?"

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

Firebase Crashlytics reported one device (Xiaomi Redmi 4X, Android 7.1.2) with error at (I can't reproduce this issue on my own devices)

```
fun show() {
    if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(context) {
        windowManager.addView(floatView, layoutParams)
    }
}
```

> Caused by android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException Unable to add
> window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    if (prefsManager.isShowOverlay()) {
        floatingWindow.show()
    }
}
```

My apps shows the floating window when activity stops (`Activity.onStop()`), here's logs from crashlytics:

[image]

p.s. please don't reference here similar questions but for `AlertDialog` and `PopupWindow`, it's a different issue!

Comment: You are calling `show()` on `floatingWindow`. `floatingWindow` would appear to be an instance of some custom class of yours. Rather than having it hold `context` and `windowManager`, perhaps you could pass the `Activity` into `show()` and obtain the `WindowManager` on the fly.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there any difference to use application context or activity context to get window manager?

Comment: I am not certain, particularly for your use case (which I assume is using `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` to display a floating window, given your code snippet). If my guess of your use case is correct, then my gut would be that for this case you should use the `Application`, since your desired window is not tied to the activity. But, it has been quite some time since I played with system overlays like this, and my memory is fuzzy on the details.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, I use `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` and my custom class can be injected (singleton) anywhere (foreground service or activity) to show or hide this floating window (system overlay), so yeah, it uses application context from the beginning. I tested my own devices and emulators and I can't reproduce this issue.